# Netflify lambda function working locally but not in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, netlify

[image]

I'm trying to use netlify and its lambda function feature to run a node function . Based on https://css-tricks.com/using-netlify-forms-and-netlify-functions-to-build-an-email-sign-up-widget/ , I have in my functions/submission-created.js:

```
const https = require("https");

exports.handler = async event => {

const email = JSON.parse(event.body).payload.data.EMAIL
const asking = JSON.parse(event.body).payload.data.ASKING

var formData = {
    'email': email,
    'first_name': '',
    'last_name': asking,
    'lists[]': 'NUM'
};
var encoded = Object.entries(formData).map(([k, v]) => `${k}=${encodeURIComponent(v)}`).join("&");

var endpoint = 'https://api.sendfox.com/contacts/?' + encoded;

const data = JSON.stringify(formData);
const options = {

    method: 'POST',
    connection: 'keep-alive',

    headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer hhhhh',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    'content-length': data.length,

};
console.log(email);

const req = https.request(endpoint, options, (res) => {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', res.headers);

    res.on('data', (d) => {
    console.log(d);
    });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
});

req.write(data);
req.end();

return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: data
};
}
```

This works as expected when I run it locally with netlify dev, but when pushed to the github repo used by netlify to build the site, it does not work in production. How can I fix this?

The package structure looks like the screenshot:

EDIT:

the netlify.toml :

```
[build]
  functions = "./functions
```

No errors. The output on sites function tab is:

```
8:57:43 PM: 2020-12-08T01:57:43.384Z    undefined   INFO    to here
8:57:43 PM: 2020-12-08T01:57:43.390Z    8ca26edc-1f20-4c20-b038- 
79ecdf206d92    INFO    yt@ghj.org
8:57:43 PM: 2020-12-08T01:57:43.390Z    8ca26edc-1f20-4c20-b038- 
79ecdf206d92    INFO    999
8:57:43 PM: 2020-12-08T01:57:43.390Z    8ca26edc-1f20-4c20-b038- 
79ecdf206d92    INFO    yt@ghj.org
8:57:43 PM: Duration: 39.71 ms  Memory Usage: 69 MB Init Duration: 
176.22 ms
```

Comment: Do you have the `netlify.toml` config file set up the same way as in the article? Is the function not running properly, or is it not showing up in the dashboard at all?

Comment: You have elaborate a little more on this `it does not work in production.`. Are you getting any error?

Comment: Please see edit

Comment: The edit is not sufficient. What you expect vs what you get instead?

Comment: can you share you folder structure and what you used while publish

Answer (score 0):

As noted, the information you give are insufficient regarding what has gone wrong. However, I will try to answer based on what I have.

In the tutorial, I noticed the usage of [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package.
The package is used in order to setup different configuration in different environments.

It utilizes different production files related to the environments, allowing you for example to setup a `.env` file for local development, and a different one (e.g.,`.env.production`) for your production.

Based on the setup, variables setup in the respective `.env` file utilized on each environment, are loaded in the `process.env` object.

Now, on your tutorial, I noticed that you have the loading of crucial variables being loaded from `.env` such as `EMAIL_TOKEN`. I suspect that your setup expects a separate `dotenv` file for production - and by not finding it, it loads the parameters required as empty, silently. Please revise what environment it loads and what your configuration is at your environments, respectively.

Also, consider the following tutorial for working with [dotenv vars](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786).

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of incorrect settings on the API Gateway. Check what all traffic is allowed. Sometimes you may have just allowed TCP traffic. Change it to all traffic.

I could also be that you have a malformed lambda response. Check this AWS documentation
[Resolve malformed 502 Api gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/malformed-502-api-gateway/)